# MVC4 Why are these radiobuttons disabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have webpage with two text boxes and two radio buttons and one submit button.
If I wanna show the page, both of the radio buttons are disabled. I have tried true and false. And I have tried this way:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyWeb"))
{
    <span class="label">Company:</span><input id="txtCompany" name="Company" type="text" size="50" /><br />
    <br />
    <span class="label">Branche:</span><input id="txtBranche" name="Branche" type="text" size="50" /><br />
    <br />
    <span class="label">En:</span><input type="radio" name="AND" checked /><<br />
    <span class="label">Of:</span><input type="radio" name="OR" checked="checked"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
    <br />
}
```

My question is why the radio buttons are disabled? The rest of page is only selected text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not actually disabled, its just that they cant be 'unselected' because there is no alternative selection.

Your radio buttons have different names ("AND" and "OR") which mean they do not belong to the same group. Make the names the same as the property you want to bind to on postback. In this case, property `string MyProperty` will be either "AND" or "OR" depending on the selection

```
<input type="radio" name="MyProperty" value="AND" checked /> // this on will be checked
<input type="radio" name="MyProperty" value ="OR"/>
```

Note. I strongly recommend you learn to use the strongly typed html helpers rather than trying to write html by hand

Comment: Everything works fine now. The last thing I had to do, was adding the latest building dll on my website.